# Висит (не работает) header("Location: url");

Tags: header, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Подробно я постарался рассказать/показать [на видео](https://youtu.be/2k-V_qrdELQ) (2 мин).

Суть проблемы в том, что header location вместо редиректа зависает намертво, в месте с сервером (любые другие страницы тоже становятся недоступны). Может, кто сталкивался подобной проблемой?

Comment: А что в логах?

Comment: А если вызвать страницу, на которую происходит переадресовка напрямую, что происходит? В php.ini включены все ошибки error_reporting(E_ALL) и display_errors=On? вначале кода там есть require и Autoload, может, они посылают какие-то заголовки? Попробуйте поставить этот redirect в самом начале страницы перед всем остальным кодом, и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: заметил особенность. Что если внутри метода (см. скриншот) проходит запрос через get_file_contents, то тогда висит. 

скрин 1: https://yadi.sk/i/-rysBqcufTAJV
скрин 2: https://yadi.sk/i/ZZUOnM2cfTAKx
скрин 3: https://yadi.sk/i/mjT5n4ZdfTCH4

Comment: Может тогда если вначале поставить ob_start(); поможет?

Comment: попробовал тоже не сработало. Видимо нужен бубен : ))
Также проверил редирект до ответа от метода - проходит без проблем

    //если была отправлена форма
       if($_POST["method_type"]):

     //header("Location: http://local.vitsenko/face/main.php"); exit();
     //ob_start();
            $res_post = $SETTINGS->edit($_POST);

            if($res_post["error_id"] == 1){

    //print_r($res_post); exit();

    header("Location: http://local.vitsenko/face/main.php"); exit();
   }
   else{ $error = $res_post["error_desc"]."<br />".$res_post["error_code"]; }

   //ob_end_clean();

       endif;

Comment: это явно как-то связано с get_file_contents, возможно, после ответа от get_file_contents нельзя делать редирект? хотя тогда вопрос, почему редирект проходит на внешние страницы (example: google.com) и не проходит на внутренние?

Comment: ob_start(); должен быть в самом верху страницы.

Comment: Что говорит headers_sent() ?

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ответы. Не мог ответить на ваши комментарии (не было кнопки ответить, не достаточно очков итд.). 

На данный момент пока полная загадка, ob_start не помог, headers_sent = false. Но! главная зацепка из того, что заметил это редирект не проходит, только на внутренние страницы, и зависает только если был сделан запрос через get_file_contents к Yandex переводчику. В остальных случаях проблемы не замечено..